# How to remove a container disk and reclaim the space onto my main partition?

Tags: catalina, bootcamp, partition

I purchased a secondhand iMac in which the previous owner manually deleted his data instead of just restoring to factory settings. It was rough getting it started but we got there in the end. The only thing left is this: he originally had a bootcamp partition on his hard drive, but when he deleted his data it left behind an empty container with 150.85 GB in it. I want to use Bootcamp to create a Windows partition on my hard drive, but it just wants to create a new partition, and I would rather just get rid of this container and then use Bootcamp to do it properly. I'm running Catalina 10.15.6 - How do I do this?

Here's the diskutil list
[image]

Here's my disk utility
[image]

Here's the container
[image]

I found a similar post that gave Terminal commands, and that would be fine - I just couldn't figure out how to adjust it to fit my situation. Other instructions are fine, too, I just want this container gone.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Suggestion to help you visualise what is going on in Disk Utility is go to the menu bar and choose View -> Show All Devices.  Then you will see the physical devices and something much close to what is disclosed by diskutil list.

Comment: Can you include an image of the pie chart displayed after you click "Partition"?

Answer (score 0):

1. Choose Partition from the toolbar and confirm you wish to partition if prompted.
2. Select the container you wish to remove from the pie chart, then click the minus button at the bottom to remove it.
3. Adjust the handles on the pie chart segments to expand the previous container into the space left by removing the other container (if this doesn't occur automatically).

Comment: The minus button is grayed out for that particular container.

Comment: It says "You can’t remove this volume, because the preceding volume cannot be resized."

Answer (score 0):

The following sequence of commands can be used to fix your problem. Here the assumption is your current output from `diskutil list` matches the image you posted.

Open a Terminal application window and enter the following commands.

```
sudo diskutil apfs deletecontainer disk1s3
sudo erasevolume free none disk1s3
sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk1s2 0
```

> Note: This question has been asked and answered before for APFS containers on a single drive. Your question involves two drives. Regardless, the answers are the same.